# How do I show error bars around my SVM results?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, error

Suppose I have an SVM with an accuracy and an F1-score, and I use that SVM to classify new daily data. If I was to then plot results by day, how do I show the error?

Do I need to use the accuracy as the probability of success and model it as a Bernoulli trial and look at the standard deviation of the binomial distribution of probabilities?

Comment: Bootstrapping??

Comment: @SmallChess Could you please explain how that translates to error bars?